# Docker: ERROR: [doc=sitecore://master/] unknown field 'schedule_t_en'

Tags: docker

I am trying to generate Docker images for xp1 and for that I performed below steps:

1. I ran `.\init`.
2. After that I ran `.\build -topology xp1 -buildConfiguration debug`
3. Then ran `.\up -topology xp1`

but `xxx-sc-solr-init-1` is not getting up, I am getting this message in log file `2022-12-01 00:03:41 Sitecore collections are already exist. Use collection name prefix different from 'sitecore'.`

[image]

This is docker file:

```
# escape=`

ARG BASE_IMAGE
ARG SXA_IMAGE

FROM ${SXA_IMAGE} as sxa
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

# Add SXA module
COPY --from=sxa C:\module\solr\cores-sxa.json C:\data\cores-sxa.json
```

[image]
In in CM log I am getting below error:

```
2022-12-01 00:17:46 <lst name="responseHeader">
2022-12-01 00:17:46   <int name="rf">1</int>
2022-12-01 00:17:46   <int name="status">400</int>
2022-12-01 00:17:46   <int name="QTime">4</int>
2022-12-01 00:17:46 </lst>
2022-12-01 00:17:46 <lst name="error">
2022-12-01 00:17:46   <lst name="metadata">
2022-12-01 00:17:46     <str name="error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str>
2022-12-01 00:17:46     <str name="root-error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str>
2022-12-01 00:17:46   </lst>
2022-12-01 00:17:46   <str name="msg">ERROR: [doc=sitecore://master/{a6599689-3616-4938-a5bb-9ec65480d2f3}?lang=en&amp;ver=1&amp;ndx=sitecore_master_index] unknown field 'schedule_t_en'</str>
2022-12-01 00:17:46   <int name="code">400</int>
2022-12-01 00:17:46 </lst>
2022-12-01 00:17:46 </response>
2022-12-01 00:17:46 
2022-12-01 00:17:46 Source: SolrNet
2022-12-01 00:17:46    at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
2022-12-01 00:17:46    at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.Post(String relativeUrl, String s)
2022-12-01 00:17:46    at SolrNet.Impl.LowLevelSolrServer.SendAndParseHeader(ISolrCommand cmd)
2022-12-01 00:17:46    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrBatchUpdateContext.Commit()
2022-12-01 00:17:46    at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.PerformUpdate(IEnumerable`1 indexableInfo, IndexingOptions indexingOptions)
2022-12-01 00:17:46 
2022-12-01 00:17:46 Nested Exception
2022-12-01 00:17:46 
2022-12-01 00:17:46 Exception: System.Net.WebException
2022-12-01 00:17:46 Message: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
2022-12-01 00:17:46 Source: System
2022-12-01 00:17:46    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
2022-12-01 00:17:46    at HttpWebAdapters.Adapters.HttpWebRequestAdapter.GetResponse()
2022-12-01 00:17:46    at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.GetResponse(IHttpWebRequest request)
2022-12-01 00:17:46    at SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.PostStream(String relativeUrl, String contentType, Stream content, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
2022-12-01 00:17:46 
2022-12-01 00:17:46
```

Answer (score 1):

Docker can get confused if cores with that name already exist.

So you can either change it to a new prefix in the .env file:

```
SOLR_CORE_PREFIX_NAME=sitecore-xm-demo
```

or go to your `\docker\data\solr` and delete the solr cores there and do an docker compose up again.

Comment: What does this error meaning ERROR: [doc=sitecore://master/{a6599689-3616-4938-a5bb-9ec65480d2f3}?lang=en&amp;ver=1&amp;ndx=sitecore_master_index] unknown field 'schedule_t_en'?

Comment: I guess this could be an misconfiguration of the Solr schema.xml. Is this an out of the box image of XP1 you are using from the repo or is it modified?
You might be best off asking in the 'Docker' channel on Sitecore Slack.

Comment: @SwatiGupta that error means that field is unknown to Solr. Solr does not have such field configured but its receiving it via get/post call to Solr.